# Better way to reorder list elements in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to re-order the result of `Tally[Characters["2723198931"]]` according to its every element's first component in the order of `lst = {"3", "1", "2", "9"}`. That is, I want the output to be `{{{"3", 2}}, {{"1", 2}}, {{"2", 2}}, {{"9", 2}}}`.

Currently I have a sort of ugly solution, but wonder if anybody can help to give a succinct solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be quite fast, but I didn't test it.  On long lists you may get better performance using `Dispatch[rls]`.

```
key = {"3", "1", "2", "9"};
tal = Tally[Characters["2723198931"]];

rls = #[[1]] -> # & /@ tal;
key /. rls
```

```
{{"3", 2}, {"1", 2}, {"2", 2}, {"9", 2}}
```

Alternatively you could use this, which is little faster for long Tally lists:

```
rls = Thread[tal[[All, 1]] -> tal];
```

Answer (score 5):

one way may be

```
data = Tally[Characters["2723198931"]];
lst = {"3", "1", "2", "9"};

(*algorithm*)

pos =  Position[data[[All, 1]], #] & /@ lst;
Extract[data, pos]
```

output

```
{{{"3", 2}}, {{"1", 2}}, {{"2", 2}}, {{"9", 2}}}
```

**Update 2:37 am**

screen shot of the above, I am using v 8.04 on windows 7

[image]

Comment: This is like what I did, even though I used `Select` instead. Is there any built-in function or even simpler method? Thanks!

Comment: This does not work for me as written.  I need `Position[data[[All, 1]], #][[1]]`.  Does it work as written in version 8?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard , It works as written for me on V 8.04, please see screen shot!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could do something like

```
With[{tal = Tally[Characters["2723198931"]]},
  Flatten@Pick[tal, tal[[All, 1]], #] & /@ key]
```

Are you always counting characters in a string? If so it might be more efficient to count the characters directly instead of transforming it to a list of characters first. Consider for example

```
str = StringJoin[RandomChoice[CharacterRange["0", "9"], 1000]];
key = {"3", "1", "2", "9"};

({#, StringCount[str, #]} & /@ key) // Timing

(* output: {0.000121, {{"3", 98}, {"1", 112}, {"2", 99}, {"9", 107}}} *)

With[{tal = Tally[Characters[str]]},
  Flatten@Pick[tal, tal[[All, 1]], #] & /@ key] // Timing 

(* output: {0.000567, {{"3", 98}, {"1", 112}, {"2", 99}, {"9", 107}}} *)
```

Comment: A problem with these methods is that you scan the list for every value in the `key`.  This doesn't matter much if the example is representative if actual use, but on longer `Tally` sets its highly inefficient.  On a key/tally length of 5000, `key /. Dispatch@Thread[tal[[All, 1]] -> tal]` is over 330X faster.  Since this is not longer than `Pick`, and since the simple version is far shorter and still faster, I prefer to promulgate that method.  If the `StringCount` method alone were presented I would vote for it as it is appropriate to the domain.